# Picard wants Tea, Earl Grey, Hot! - How does the computer know how hot "hot" is?

Tags: star-trek, computers, jean-luc-picard

On Star Trek: The Next Generation, Captain Jean-Luc Picard wants his tea "**[Earl Grey, Hot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2IJdfxWtPM)!**" How does the computer know exactly how hot to make it? For instance, I'm drinking my tea at **50-55c** right now, but some people like it at **60 or even 70c** which is just too hot for me.

How hot is Picard's tea?

Comment: I've added this as a dupe. Either Picard has told it the precise temperature he wants his tea and it's remembered, or Picard has tried the varieties of temperature of tea on offer *as standard* and simply selected which one he likes best.

Comment: I would imagine, too, that if he ordered "hot" tea and then came back with a request like "no, 5 degrees hotter", the computer would remember that for next time. Federation computers are extremely capable at picking up on language cues except when the plot requires them not to.

Comment: In a ship 'hot' is exactly what the Captain wishes it to be.

Comment: We know from All Good Things that his preferred type of tea was programmed into the replicator shortly after his arrival on board.

Comment: That raises the question of how often he wants his tea "Irish Breakfast, standard heat."

Comment: "A little too hot. A bit cooler next time, please."
"Now it is a little too cold."
"Perfect! Remember this setting."

Comment: Is this not a case of simply wanting "hot" tea as opposed to "iced tea"?

Comment: The ship's computer in Star Trek also has a displayed (if not proven) ability to read people's minds.  Doors open automatically, but *only when a person intends to walk through them.* If a person walks right up to the door and then stops to say a parting line, the door remains closed until they're done and then opens as they begin moving again.  (Riker does this a lot on TNG IIRC.). Also, the universal translator can apparently translate languages of aliens that have *never been encountered before* in **real time** only moments after the Enterprise finds them.

Comment: If the aliens have never had contact with the Federation before, it seems unlikely that their communications protocols would just "work together" from the word go.

Comment: The computer learned what temp Picard likes by trial and error. If it wasn't hot enough he would shout "Not hot enough, dammit! Not hot enough!" until the computer finally got it right. This was from a deleted scene in Encounter at Farpoint that was never filmed, or written.

Comment: If the replicator is keyed to his voice and remembers his specific temperature preference, why even specify hot?

Comment: @Celestialgranturismo Vote to reopen and let's find out